# I have a problem Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id) when I change the permission file ir.model.access.csv and upgrade the module

Tags: python, module, permissions, upgrade, odoo-12

I have created my own module in odoo 12. And I have changed the permission file- `ir.model.access.csv`. All the code is as below.

ir.model.access.csv:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_customer_customer,access.customer.customer,model_customer_customer,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
```

.models/models:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class CustomerCustomer(models.Model):

    _name = 'customer.customer'


    name = fields.Char(string= 'Name', required=True)
    place = fields.Char(string='Place')
    photo = fields.Binary(string='Image')
    age = fields.Integer(string='Age')
    dob = fields.Date(string='Date of Birth')
```

error message occurs when I try to upgrade my module and install the module I created from odoo 12

> Exception: Module loading custom_customer failed: file custom_customer\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
>    No matching record found for external id 'model_customer_customer' in field 'Object'
>   Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)

Comment: Try restarting server, check init file if you added file name there, comment csv file from manefest then update and again uncomment and update

Comment: Hi, Check if your file "CustomerCustomer" is imported in the __init__.py file

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have added the file name in **init**.py inside the model folder and also please check whether model folder is added in the main **init**.py file